# Post Json Restkit unable to find a routable path for object of type for HTTP Method 'POST'

Tags: xcode, json, post, restkit

I want to send a simple Json to my server and get a Json response with my iPad app.. I use Restkit to do all my work, but I've a problem with the POST of Json.
This is the simple Json request that I want:

```
{"id_partita":"2"}
```

And the response will be like this:

```
[{"id":34,"id_dispositivo":"123","id_partita":2,"allenatore":0,"giocatore1":"AAA","giocatore2":"BBB",...}]
```

This is my code in Xcode:

```
-(void) post
{
    RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"mysite"];
    RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    // Setup object mappings
    RKObjectMapping *formazioneMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Formazione class]];

    [formazioneMapping mapKeyPath:@"id_formazione"
                                toAttribute:@"id_formazione"];
    [formazioneMapping mapKeyPath:@"id_dispositivo"
                                toAttribute:@"id_dispositivo"];
    [formazioneMapping mapKeyPath:@"id_partita"
                                toAttribute:@"id_partita"];
    [formazioneMapping mapKeyPath:@"formazione"
                                toAttribute:@"formazione"];
    [formazioneMapping mapKeyPath:@"giocatore1"
                                toAttribute:@"giocatore1"];
    [formazioneMapping mapKeyPath:@"giocatore2"
                                toAttribute:@"giocatore2"];
;

    // Register our mappings with the provider
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:formazioneMapping forKeyPath:@""];

    [objectManager.router routeClass:[Formazione class]
                      toResourcePath:@"/formazione/index.php"
                           forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    // Set serialization MIME type.
    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;

    // Configure a serialization mapping for our Formazione class. We want to send id_partita
    RKObjectMapping *formazionePOSTSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping
                                                      mappingForClass:[Formazione class]];
    [formazionePOSTSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"id_partita", nil];

    // Now register the mapping with the provider
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:formazionePOSTSerializationMapping forClass: [Formazione class]];

    FormazionePOST *formazionePOST = [[FormazionePOST alloc] init];
    formazionePOST.id_partita = @"2";
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:formazionePOST delegate:self];

}
```

But I've this error when I try to execute it:
'Unable to find a routable path for object of type 'FormazionePOST' for HTTP Method 'POST''.

I don't understand what's my mistakes, I can't find a simple example of POST and GET a Json.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem using AfNetworking instead RestKit.
There are lot of examples for JSON managment in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it that in your router init you refer to the Formazione class but you are trying to post FormazionePost class?